# random contacts in android

Tags: android, string, random, contacts

I have created an activity that inserts a new contact in phonebook.

Now I need to be able to generate random contacts such as random display names, phone numbers and emails for testing purposes.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This site may be of use [http://www.fakenamegenerator.com](http://www.fakenamegenerator.com/order.php)

You don't say if you're generating the names on the device or elsewhere so not sure if you can use this or not

Comment: I want to generate these names and then add them to the contacts. that site only lets me add one phone number

Comment: Hi you can order up to 50,000 contacts in one file but you'll need a way of reading that generated file (csv, sqlite, etc..) in your app